# angular-cli do not bundle the style files in order when using AOT

Tags: angular

in my `.angular-cli.json`, the `styles` property like this:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "adminlte.css",
    "../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/skin-yellow-light.min.css"
  ],
```

I expect these files will bundle in that order, but I got the `styles.bundle.css` like this:

```
AdminLTE ...... styles ...... skin-yellow-light ...... bootstrap ......
```

This lead to my project's style are different from dev mode after I build it.
So I wonder why.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by `@import` all the style files into `styles.css`, so my `angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css"
]
```

and `styles.css`:

```
/* import other style files */
@import "./styles/bootstrap.min.css";
@import './styles/adminlte.css';
@import './styles/skin-yellow-light.min.css';

/* some global styles */
```